# Merging switch statement from different class

Tags: javascript, typescript, merge

Is there a way to combine `switch` statements from 2 different class, but with the same function name into 1, other than overriding the function and writing the `switch` statement manually, or somehow copy-pasting the `switch` from ClassB and paste it after the `switch` from ClassA?

Class A:

```
protected casesHandler(): void
    {
        switch (case){
            case 0:
                break;
            default:
                super.caseHandler();
        }
    }
```

Class B:

```
protected casesHandler(): void
    {
        switch (case){
            case 1:
                break;
            default:
                super.caseHandler();
        }
    }
```

desire outcome:

```
protected casesHandler(): void
    {
        switch (case){
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
            default:
                super.caseHandler();
        }
    }
```

---

trying to avoid:

```
protected casesHandler(): void
    {
        switch (case){
            case 0:
                break;
            default:
                super.caseHandler();
        }

        switch (case){
            case 1:
                break;
            default:
                super.caseHandler();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Lets say ClassA and ClassB is actually some kind of plugin. Both extends ClassC. So depends on situation, Class A and ClassB will be use accordingly. But on some special cases, both functions of plugin are needed. By default, class A and class B is actually super back to the same function in Class C. Or can just ignore the default for now.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of doing that, but even if you could do it somehow, it doesn't look like clean code.

You could just isolate this logic into a simple function and import where you need it:

```
export const casesHandler = (case: number): void => {
  switch (case) {
    case 0:
      // code
    case 1:
      // code
    default:
      // code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These functions aren't similar. `super` in `super.caseHandler()` is hard-coded to specific parent class. So `default` is different in these `casesHandler` methods, and there's nothing wrong in overriding `casesHandler`.

In order to achieve that, there could be abstractions that follow some convention:

```
protected casesHandler(): boolean {
    switch (case) {
        case 0:
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

protected casesWithDefaultHandler(): void
    const isCaseSolved = this.casesHandler();

    if (!isCaseSolved)
        super.caseHandler();
}
```

Then several `casesHandler` functions could be composed.

Comment: ok, Lets say ClassA and ClassB is actually some kind of plugin. Both extends ClassC. So depends on situation, Class A and ClassB will be use accordingly. But on some special cases, both functions of plugin are needed. By default, class A and class B actually super back to the same function in Class C. Or can just ignore the default for now.

Comment: I guess casesHandler from the code above will work then. 'default' action is excluded, so nothing prevents them from being composed.